# Finding general time complexity for recurrence relation $T(n)=aT(n/\alpha)+bT(\beta n/\alpha)+f(n)$

Tags: time-complexity, asymptotics, big-o-notation

I was given an assignment in which I had multiple recurrence relations and I had to find their Big-oh time complexities. Nearly all of the recurrence relations were of the form as under:

> $$T(n)=aT(n/\alpha)+bT(\beta n/\alpha)+f(n)$$

So I tried to find the general Big-oh complexity, so that I could solve each one just by substituting in the particular coefficient values. Here is what I did:

$$\begin{aligned}
T(n)&=a\left(aT\left(\frac{n}{\alpha^{2}}\right)+bT\left(\frac{\beta n}{\alpha^{2}}\right)+f\left(\frac{n}{\alpha}\right)\right)+b\left(aT\left(\frac{\beta n}{\alpha^{2}}\right)+bT\left(\frac{\beta^{2} n}{\alpha^{2}}\right)+f\left(\frac{\beta n}{\alpha}\right)\right)+f(n)\\ 
&=\left(a^{2}T\left(\frac{n}{\alpha^{2}}\right)+2abT\left(\frac{\beta n}{\alpha^{2}}\right)+b^{2}T\left(\frac{\beta^{2}n}{\alpha^{2}}\right)\right)+\left(f(n)+af\left(\frac{n}{\alpha}\right)+bf\left(\frac{\beta n}{\alpha}\right)\right)\\
&=\sum_{r=0}^{k}{k\choose r}a^{k-r}b^{r}T\left(\frac{\beta^{r}n}{\alpha^{k}}\right)+\sum_{r=0}^{k-1}\sum_{i=0}^{r}{r\choose i}a^{r-i}b^{i}f\left(\frac{\beta^{i}n}{\alpha^{r}}\right)
\end{aligned}$$
$$\boxed{O\left[\max\left(\sum_{r=0}^{k}{k\choose r}a^{k-r}b^{r}T\left(\frac{\beta^{r}n}{\alpha^{k}}\right), \sum_{r=0}^{k-1}\sum_{i=0}^{r}{r\choose i}a^{r-i}b^{i}f\left(\frac{\beta^{i}n}{\alpha^{r}}\right)\right)\right]\text{ where } k=\log_{\alpha}n}
$$

Is this correct? When I apply it on a specific example, I'm not sure if I get the right answer. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this (for well-behaved $f$) using the [Akra–Bazzi theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method), a generalization of the master theorem. The answer will depend on the relation between the parameters $a,b,\alpha,\beta$ and the asymptotics of $f$.